# $T: P_4 \to P_2$ such that ker$(T) =$ span$\{1+ x, 2 + x\}$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, solution-verification

> Is there a linear transformation $T: P_4 \to P_2$ such that ker$(T) =$ span$\{1+ x, 2 + x\}$?

---

My claim is such a $T$ exists:

Let $B = \{ 1+x,2+x,x^2,x^3,x^4\}$ be a basis of $P_4$ and $\{1,x,x^2\}$ be a basis of $P_2$.

We define the following:

$T(1+x) =0, T(2+x) = 0, T(x^2) = 1, T(x^3) = x$ and $T(x^4) = x^2$ and this $T$ satisfies all the conditions.

---

Is the proof fine?

Comment: Your example is perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes but you should justify that $\{1+x,2+x,x^2,x^3,x^4\}$ is a basis. Alternatively you could write your map with respect to the standard basis (it is very simple in this form - just calculate $T(1),T(x)$.)

Comment: @tkf B is a basis , it can be easily seen, as it is linearly independent.

Comment: @Subhajit it depends on context.  If this was a question in its own right, then I would not give full marks without a little more explanation.  On the other hand if this was one step of a proof in a more advanced topic, then further explanation would be excessive.

Comment: You can take $\{2,6x,12x^2\}$  as basis of $P_2$, then it is easy to define $T=\frac{d^2}{dx^2} $